# Is there any way to set the search options per column in jqGrid 3.4.4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

So I'm using [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) with my mvc.net / Ling2Sql prototype site that I'm making and I've done the work to get jqGrids search functionality up and running.  Its pretty sweet actually, but since you cant search by >, >=, < or <= with strings, I wanted to setup the search options per column.

I know I can set the overall search options for the table by doing:

```
jQuery("#search").searchGrid( {sopt:['cn','bw','eq','ne','lt','gt','ew']} );
```

But I want something on a per column basis, so the user maintains the ability to search >, >=, < and <= on int columns but not on string columns.

On a whim I tried this and it didn't work

```
<snip>
colNames:['Id', 'form2', 'form3'],
colModel:[
 {name:'ID',    index:'FormID', width:20, sopt:['ne','lt']},
 {...},
 {...}
 ]
<snip>
```

I'm going to guess I'd have to dive fairly deep into jqGrid to add this functionality, but I just wanted to see if it wasn't an option already built in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that particular version, there is no way to do it without diving somewhat deeper into the codebase and adding functionality.

Answer (score 3):

Allen,
I know it's been awhile, but Tony just released jqgrid 3.5 out of beta, so you might want to upgrade...

If you look at the [wiki page for colModel](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options) (which probably assumes 3.5), then the option "searchoptions:[sopt[...]]" is what you'll want to use.

Try it out with 3.4.4...